# Merge together all actions of a single user on a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [New reputation is too verbose: upvote/unupvote, upvote again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again)

#### Update:

Feature request:

Please merge all the update of one user to one line.

---

Look at this user: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132601/wfaulk?tab=reputation

He had one post today which I up and down downvoted (i did it multiple times to be sure):

[image: why?]

Why do we need to show all of that?

If I upvote and then downvote all in a row like that, what is the reason to show that off? (especially if it all came from the same user!)

Screenshot of Question:

[image: OP]

Question link: [Ignore responses to ignored users in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123691/155556)

Comment: http://images.cheezburger.com/completestore/2010/6/19/a5522e5c-d046-4915-8100-d8eed7b2031a.jpg

Comment: ....why would you do that?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas :-P haha. awesome ^_^

Comment: I can actually think of a very specific reason to keep and expose this information, although how useful it is in practice I cannot say... Anyone remember "tactical down-voting"?

Comment: At least that display will tell the user why their reputation fluctuated so much over seven minutes...

Answer (score 8):

I'm with Nick. The answer here is for people to think before they click. There's little point trying to apply a code solution to this behavior problem.

(And yes, I realize that in your specific case, it was done as an example.)

Answer (score 4):

If you voted 18 times on a single question or answer, why shouldn't the record reflect that? If you find that the number of votes represented on your reputation is excessive you should try to be more judicious in your voting. It's reasonable to change a vote after someone makes an edit, but it'd be strange to do that more than once or twice in a short time period.

Answer (score 2):

I think a small logic tweak for this would be a better solution. When you submit an upvote to a user's post, it should always leave that mark in their history. If you then retract that upvote, it should also mark the "unupvote" event. However, if you then re-upvote the post, I think it should remove the "unupvote" event. Go two levels deep. This way, it's like the unupvote never happened. I think this would be a good solution to keeping the reputation history clean, while still preventing users becoming confused about their reputation.

Comment: Trust me when I say this would by no means a "small logic tweak" :)