# The reputation page reports two down-votes when it should report just one

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I down-voted [a question here on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123773/problems-with-twtweetcomposeviewcontroller) that was first closed by five users, and then deleted by a moderator.
My reputation shows a down-vote, a un-down-vote, and a down-vote (the reputation list is ordered by time).

[image: screenshot]

While I understand the down-vote, and the "reversed down-vote," I don't understand the third entry. The question doesn't have an answer; therefore, all the entries are referring to the question, which is where the link reported in those entries takes me.

I simple down-voted the question; I didn't down-vote, then reversed it, and down-voted again. The question is still shown down-voted from me.

[image: screenshot]

Why does the reputation list report three entries, instead of two? Is that the expected behavior?

#### Update

Looking at my reputation page, I now see just two entries about that question.

[image: screenshot]

To make a comparison, in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88162/is-the-rep-cap-still-employed-what-is-the-point-of-it-and-where-can-i-find-det/) (now deleted) I had an answer that was up-voted twice, and accepted. My reputation page reports the following, for that question:

[image: screenshot]

It reports that I lost the reputation gained with the up-votes (2), and because my answer was removed as accepted answer. One of the two entries is reported as *deleted* which doesn't happen with the other question.

Comment: So you did not reverse the downvote at all?  Because according to [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123696/merge-together-all-actions-of-a-single-user-on-a-question), the new page shows every vote action separately.

Comment: No, I didn't. I down-voted the question when I see it, as it was clearly an off-topic question for Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Cool, just making sure =)  It seems pretty sensitive, so if you clicked the down arrow three times in a row, I could imagine it showing up like that.  But it seems like you may have actually found a bug.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the recent change in how [votes on deleted questions still count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions/123048#123048).  So 1. you downvote. 2. Downvote is removed because the question is deleted (old behavior). 3. Downvote is restored in order to count on your profile (new behavior).

Comment: It could be possibly related, but that feature request was about counting as casted votes also the ones casted for deleted posts. The reputation page should not report three entries, as that would show me, in the case I down-voted an answer, that I lose 1 point, get it back, and then lose it again; if that would be the case, my reputation history doesn't match the reputation I really have.

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  Not sure why the reputation tab would show you voting on questions at all (since that never affects your reputation).  +1 from me.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Voting on questions doesn't affect reputation? News to me

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange): "2011-05-12: Question downvotes are 'free' to the downvoter and will not be subject to a -1 rep penalty. Downvotes to answers are unaffected and still 'cost' 1 reputation to cast."

Comment: @Lightness In more words - There is a reputation penalty (for the *voter*) for downvoting an answer (-1).  There is no such penalty for downvoting questions.  Obviously, voting on questions always affects the *votee* (the question-owner) =)

Comment: I had no idea..