# Too much detail in reputation tab?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New reputation is too verbose: upvote/unupvote, upvote again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again)

A snip of my current one:

[image]

Can't really phantom what they're thinking.  I very much do appreciate the accuracy, thanks for doing that tough job Nick.

I'll ask for something I've been meaning to request.  Can you make it blue instead of red?

Comment: Blue is already taken for bounties.

Comment: Related: [Merge together all actions of a single user on a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123696/merge-together-all-actions-of-a-single-user-on-a-question).

Comment: @thirtydot - shoot, I'll re-ask for eric-lippert-purple.

Comment: Perhaps it would be reasonable to hide/remove votes that were cancelled within the grace period.

Comment: We're going to look at a rollup here, but our highest priority is making sure reputation is constantly accurate, then we'll worry more on the UI side...bear with it just a little while and we'll get to it.

Comment: Okidoki, sounds like a plan.  I wasn't kidding about the color change request btw.

Comment: @Nick - I did see such an accuracy problem.  Look at BalusC, Feb 15 13:04 vs Feb 17 03:00.  +20 vs -70.

Comment: This Accept/UnAccept/Accept and upvote/unupvote happens _a lot_. Without the timestamps I would have thought it a bug in the registration or reporting. A roll-up per user would be very welcome.

Comment: Uphill: that color request should really be a separate question.

Comment: @Henk - I *did* make it my primary ask.  But yes, odds are low they'll take it seriously.  Such are the hazards of answering questions and not participate in the ruckus here.

Comment: This question covers exactly the same ground as **earlier questions**.