# Strange rendering in rep log when answer is accepted/unaccepted/accepted

Tags: bug

I'm seeing a minor anomaly with the way the new reputation system is rendering the loss of reputation for unaccepted answers. It appears that one of [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977492/am-i-using-gcc-wrong/6977504#6977504) was accepted, unaccepted and then accepted again, all in the same second or so, and the two accepts are merged into a single event.

This is what I'm seeing:

[image: merged accept events]

This is what I *should* be seeing:

[image: unmerged accept events]

Or, alternatively, all three events merged into a single "accept" event since they seem to have happened at the same time, possibly due to the user accidentally mashing the accept button.

Comment: I found the same thing. And I am totally sure I never got unaccept. I receive this for each question I got upvote and accept.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge together all actions of a single user on a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123696/merge-together-all-actions-of-a-single-user-on-a-question)

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm actually suggesting the opposite of that question. Where he is asking for them to be merged, I am pointing out that they *are* merged, and incorrectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New reputation is too verbose: upvote/unupvote, upvote again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again)